# Proof language classification using reduction mapping

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I am required to determine whether the following language is in $R$/$RE$-$R$/$coRE$-$RE$ or neither.

$$L = \{\langle M \rangle |\ M\ \text{is a}\ TM\ \text{and}\ \exists x\ \text{s.t.}\ |x|<5\ \text{and}\ M\ \text{rejects}\ x\}$$

This is my thought of doing:
Building a reduction mapping $F$: $A_{TM}\rightarrow L$

$F$ = "On input $\langle M,w \rangle$:

- Generate $M'$ = 'On input $x$:

  - Simulate $M$ on $w$:

    - If it accepts $\Rightarrow$ if $|x| < 5$ reject. Else $\Rightarrow$  accept.
    - Otherwise $\Rightarrow$ accept.'
  - Return $\langle M’\rangle$"

Correctness:
$$\langle M,w\rangle \in A_{TM} \iff M\ \text{accepts}\ w \iff \text{all}\ |x| < 5\ \text{rejected} \iff \langle M’\rangle \in L$$
$$\langle M,w\rangle \notin A_{TM} \iff M\ \text{doesn’t accept}\ w  \iff  \text{No}\ x\ \text{is rejected} \iff \langle M’\rangle \notin L$$

I'm not quite sure if I've used the mapping reduction correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The proof of correctness contains a couple of errors. The condition that all $x: |x| < 5$ are rejected does not imply that $M$ accepts $w$. The reason is that $M$ may reject $w$ by hanging. For the same reason the fact that $M$ does not accept $w$ does not imply that $M'$ accepts every string.

Here is a working reduction from $A_{TM}$ to $L$.

$F$ = "On input $\langle M,w\rangle$:

1. Construct the following machine $M'$.

   $M'$ = "On input $x$:

   1. If $|x| \ge 5$, *accept*.
   2. Otherwise, run $M$ on $w$. If it accepts, *accept*; if it rejects, *reject*."
2. Output $\langle M'\rangle$"

It is not difficult to see that $\langle M,w\rangle \in A_{TM}$ if and only if $\langle M'\rangle \in L$.